# Como imprimir un pdf con datos y lineas de guía

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

antes de empezar aclaro que soy novato y últimamente he estado muy perezoso para estudiar. Les cuento que descubrí un problema en mi lugar de trabajo y se me ocurrió la solución "milagrosa", ya que siempre fue una tarea que nadie quería hacer. La hoja que ven a continuación son rótulos o fichas técnicas de identificación de obras de arte, se diseñan en photoshop se imprimen se cortan y se pegan en la pared junto con la obra con el fin de que el usuario conozca los datos de la obra. Entonces como le tienen alergia al photoshop se me ocurrió que sería genial tener una app web que con solo escribir los datos esta genere un pdf con el resultado mostrado en la imagen 1 incluyendo las lineas de cortes que ven en las esquinas de cada rotulo. Como la idea es mucho para un novato como yo, le pedí ayuda a Chat GPT después de varias instrucciones y el resultado fue el siguiente...ver imagen 2, es importante señalar que por ahora tengo 2 formularios en el HTML, cuando lleno ambos y le doy al botón MOSTRAR RESULTADOS, me genera 2 pdf y cada uno con 4 rótulos pero con los datos repetidos y lo que quiero es que me genere 1 solo pdf con 8 rótulos con datos diferentes ya que serían 8 obras de artes. Así como lo muestro en la imagen 1.

**Resultado deseado**

[image: Resultado deseado]

**Resultado logrado**

[image: Resultado logrado]

```js
function HTMLtoPDF() {
    var num_rotulos = 4; // Número de rótulos que queremos generar
    var author = document.getElementById("author").value;
    var title = document.getElementById("title").value;
    var date = document.getElementById("date").value;
    var technique = document.getElementById("technique").value;
    var measurements = document.getElementById("measurements").value;
    var inventory_number = document.getElementById("inventory_number").value;

    var doc = new jsPDF({
        orientation: "portrait", // Orientación vertical
        unit: "mm", // Unidades en milímetros
    });

    // Configuración de las líneas
    var line_width = 0.1; // Ancho de la línea
    var line_color = "#000"; // Color de la línea



    for (var i = 0; i < num_rotulos; i++) {
        // Calcular la posición del rótulo actual
        var x = i % 2 == 0 ? 10 : 70;
        var y = i < 2 ? 10 : 50;

        // Dibujar el rectángulo
        doc.setLineWidth(line_width);
        doc.setDrawColor(line_color);
        doc.rect(x, y, 50, 30);



        // Escribir los datos del rótulo
        doc.setFontSize(8);
        doc.setFontType("bold");
        doc.text(author, x + 2, y + 6);
        doc.setFontType("italic");
        doc.text(title, x + 2, y + 11);
        doc.setFontType("normal");
        doc.text(date, x + 2, y + 16);
        doc.text(technique, x + 2, y + 21);
        doc.text(measurements, x + 2, y + 26);
        doc.text(inventory_number, x + 32, y + 26);

        // Actualizar los valores de los datos para el próximo rótulo
        // author = " " + (i + 1);
        // title = " " + (i + 1);
        // date = " " + (i + 1);
        // technique = " " + (i + 1);
        // measurements = " " + (i + 1);
        // inventory_number = " " + (i + 1);
    }

    // Obtenemos la representación en formato data URI del PDF
    var pdfData = doc.output('datauristring');


    // Abrimos el PDF en una nueva pestaña o ventana
    var newTab = window.open();
    newTab.document.write("<iframe width='100%' height='100%' src='" + pdfData + "'></iframe>");
}


// Comportamiento del botón imprimir
function imprimir() {
    var data1 = HTMLtoPDF();
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
    <title>Generador de rotulos</title>
</head>

<body>
    <main class="container" id="HTMLtoPDF">
        <form class="form">
            
                <label id="lauthor">Autor:
                    
                </label><input type="text" id="author" name="author">
                
                <label id="ltitle">Título:
                    
                </label><input type="text" id="title" name="title">
                
                <label id="ldate">Fecha:
                    
                </label><input type="number" id="date" name="date">
                
                <label id="ltechnique">Técnica:
                    
                </label><input type="text" id="technique" name="technique">
                
                <label id="lmeasurements">Medidas:
                    
                </label><input type="text" id="measurements" name="measurements">
                
                <label id="linventory_number">Número de bien:
                    
                </label><input type="number" id="inventory_number" name="inventory_number">
                
                <a href="#" onclick="HTMLtoPDF()">Mostrar resultado</a>

        </form>

    </main>


   




    <script src="./js/jspdf.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/pdfFromHTML.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/app.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Recuerda que para que realmente tu snippet sea un [repro], debes enlazar las bibliotecas correspondientes; para que se entienda: cuando das clic a "Mostrar resultado", aparece el error _jsPDF is not defined_. Tampoco está demás mencionar que [_se desaconseja el uso de manejadores de eventos inline_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) (tales como `onclick`). Por último: no está mal usar IAs que "generan" código, pero *estudia* para ser capaz de discernir si lo que te responde es correcto/útil o no :)

Comment: Además, pon en el título a qué haces referencia con "esta app". La idea es que el título contenga un breve resumen del problema. Lee [ask].

Comment: Ya que eres novato, considera, en lugar de generar un PDF, solo generar HTML y luego lo imprimes. Suele ser bueno cuando los márgenes de las impresiones cambian en impresoras diferentes. Eso me ha resuelto tareas fáciles en el pasado.

Comment: Gracias amigo haré el intento de modificar el código para que funcione aquí, en vs code me corre bien, en codepen me da el mismo error.

Comment: Hola amigo mira el resultado que logré https://augustoalr.github.io/museo_label/ en el input de seleccion de tecnica lo hice así porque quiero en lo posible de facilitarle aun más el trabajo al usuario y evitar disminuir errores ortográficos, otro detalle es que añadí una función para que obligatoriamente todo el texto que se escriba empiece en mayusculas, estos detalles relacionados con gramatica lo hice porq cuando se genera el pdf si hay errores el usuario tendrá que escribir nuevamente los rotulos